# MySQL : if server_id is not explicitly set, then get error `ERROR 1200 (HY000) at line 1: The server is not configured as slave;`

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1

Our mysql version is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.35, for portbld-freebsd7.2 (amd64) using  5.2"

We have two database servers with replication, in a simple master/slave relationship. `mysql2` is the master, `mysql1` is the slave. A year ago, `mysql` was the master and `mysql2` was the slave. We had to reverse their roles during a hardware failure.

On the master, we explicitly set the server_id (server-id)

```
[root@mysql2 ~]# grep server-id my.cnf
server-id       = 2
[root@mysql2 ~]# mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id'"
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 2     | 
+---------------+-------+
```

But, this setting was not set in my.cnf on the slave.

```
[root@mysql1 ~]# grep server-id my.cnf
```

Whoops. This shouldn't matter, because the server_id is set to 1 by default.

```
[root@mysql1 ~]# mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id'"
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| server_id     | 1     | 
+---------------+-------+
```

If I restart mysql, then the replication will work fine.

However, if I manually "STOP SLAVE" "START SLAVE", I get an error:

```
[root@mysql1 ~]# mysql -e "STOP SLAVE;"
[root@mysql1 ~]# mysql -e "START SLAVE;"
ERROR 1200 (HY000) at line 1: The server is not configured as slave; fix in config file or with CHANGE MASTER TO
```

Why do I get this error when I don't explicitly set a value in my.cnf ? Why does replication work when I restart, but not when I "STOP SLAVE;" "START SLAVE;"?

- It appears that mysql assigned a default value to the variable `server_id`.
- According the default my.cnf, the `server_id` will default to `1`

  ```
  # required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1 
  # defaults to 1 if master-host is not set 
  # but will not function as a master if omitted 
  #server-id  = 1
  ```

The fix is to explicitly set server-id in my.cnf, as suggested by Baron Schwartz at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/08/01/why-mysql-server-not-configured-as-slave/

> server-id=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two servers are not allowed to have the same server_id. Also, [If you omit --server-id from a master, the default ID is 0, in which case a master refuses connections from all slaves, and a slave refuses to connect to a master](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-masterbaseconfig.html).

For more information, [see Section 15.1.1.2, “Setting the Replication Slave Configuration”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto-slavebaseconfig.html).

Even if both servers have different server_id values, please make sure the new master has [binary logging enabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin).

Comment: Thanks. "15.1.1.2. Setting the Replication Slave Configuration" says what we need to do. What I don't understand is why replication is working fine after a restart, and why MySQL seemed to assign a default value of '1' to 'server_id'.

Comment: I'll respond to my own comment. According to Baron Schwartz (MySQL guru, creator of Maatkit, co-author of several MySQL books), if 'server_id' is not set then MySQL can be buggy. See his description at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/08/01/why-mysql-server-not-configured-as-slave/